# How to interpolate latitude and longitude?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using MODIS Effective Radius Data which comes with Latitude and Longitude information.

Data size is [2030][1354] while lat/lon size is lat[406][270].
I need to blow up lat/lon to match data size.

My question is as follows:

How can I interpolate/fill the gaps between this information to obtain the Lat/Lon corresponding to all the data points?

Here is my code to get information for lat/lon size of lat[406][1354]
But I want to get information for lat/lon size of [2030][1354].

```
import numpy as np
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

# Open HDF4 file.
FILE_NAME = 'File.hdf'
hdf = SD(FILE_NAME, SDC.READ)
sds_obj = hdf.select('Effective Radius')

data = sds_obj.get()

lat = hdf.select('Latitude')
latnp = lat[:,:]
lon = hdf.select('Longitude')
lonnp = lon[:,:]

step1=5
step2=4
m=406
n=1354

# We need to interpolate lat and lon to match the size of data.
longitude = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.float)
latitude = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.float)

for i in range (0,  406):
#    print i
    for j in range (0,  270):
#        print j
        if j == 0:
            latitude[i,j] = latnp[i,j]
            # print latitude[i]
            longitude[i,j] = lonnp[i,j]
            continue
        if j > 0 and j < 270-1 :
            # print 'step1='+str(step1)
            count=step1*(j-1)+1
            # print 'count='+str(count)
            arr_fill=np.linspace(latnp[i,(j-1)], latnp[i, j], (step1+1))
            # print arr_fill
            latitude[i, count:count+(step1)] = arr_fill[0:step1]
            # print latitude[i]
            arr_fill=np.linspace(lonnp[i,(j-1)], lonnp[i, j], (step1+1))
            longitude[i, count:count+(step1)] = arr_fill[0:step1]
            continue
        if j == 270-1:
            count=step1*(j-1)+1
            arr_fill=np.linspace(latnp[i,(j-1)], latnp[i, j], (step2+1))
            latitude[i, count:count+(step2)] = arr_fill[0:step2]
            arr_fill=np.linspace(lonnp[i,(j-1)], lonnp[i, j], (step2+1))
            longitude[i, count:count+(step2)] = arr_fill[0:step2]
            continue
```

Comment: Are you asking what *algorithm* to use, or how to implement it?

Comment: Any type of advice, support or a code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't start with for loops.  That's slow and error prone.  Use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html.

Comment: Scripts to perform the interpolation can be found here: https://www.icare.univ-lille.fr/modis-geolocation/.  However, it is likely easier to use the MYD03 or MOD03 geolocation fields when working with MODIS 1km swath datasets.